# Is there a way I can read comments to me from deleted posts?

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-questions

Someone (I can't tell who) left a comment for me on a spam posts about do's/don't's of spam question reporting. Unfortunately I have no idea what it said except for the first few words because the spam question is gone now. It seemed like useful information. Is there an inbox or something where comments that @me are listed and I can read them in their entirety?

Answer (score 4):

Only if you can see this post. One of the following condition must be met:

- You have 10'000 reputation and [access to moderator tools](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) allows you to see all deleted posts.
- It was your question that got deleted - you can see own deleted questions and comments under them.

---

I think I can guess what you did wrong, anyway. Someone commented at you. It means you either:

- Was the spammer
- Commented spam
- Edited spam, *and by doing so bumped it up*

The **only** thing you should do with spam post is to **flag them as spam**. That's all. Do not feed them. Do not prove to spammers that you read their spam. That only encouraged them, so it is bad thing to do.

---

## Comment you are asking about is:

> @betherwisser. Please don't edit spam posts. It confuses spam filters and runs the risk of invalidating spam flags. Please see [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited) –  [Jan Dvorak](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/20137/jan-dvorak) Aug 25 at 4:50

And indeed [it was edited Aug 25 at 4:34, by you](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/127648/revisions).

---

## Special cases

As MPD ♦  [pointed out](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/is-there-a-way-i-can-read-comments-to-me-from-deleted-posts/3071?noredirect=1#comment4263_3071),

> there are some special conditions when a moderator leaves the comment. See [Does the OP of a flagged post get comment notifications if the post is deleted by mods?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85420/does-the-op-of-a-flagged-post-get-comment-notifications-if-the-post-is-deleted-b)

Comment: I didn't comment spam.

Comment: @betherwisser it is possible to comment `@you` only when you created, edited or commented post. If you got notification in any other situation, it probably was a bug.

Comment: @betherwisser can you post a link to that post? I know you will see 404 there, but about a dozen people here will be able to see the real post and it's comments. I happen to be among them, so I might simply re-post that comment for you.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127648/muscle-building-tags?noredirect=1#comment152703_127648

Comment: @betherwisser see update to my answer.

Comment: This is mostly accurate, but there are some special conditions when a moderator leaves the comment.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85420/does-the-op-of-a-flagged-post-get-comment-notifications-if-the-post-is-deleted-b

Comment: @MPD Thanks for clarification. Should I add this to my answer? Or just the link will be enough?

Comment: @Mołot The reference link is enough.  It's a fairly rare situation; mostly used with mods leaving comments on non-answer answers.